StrongSwan VPN: Unable to connect to remote LAN
I have a RHEL server and I have configured Strongswan in order to make an IPSec VPN. I can connect through the VPN and I can navigate Internet but I cannot access remote LAN.
This is my ipsec.conf
config setup
    charondebug="ike 2, knl 2, cfg 2, net 2, esp 2, dmn 2, mgr 2"
    uniqueids=no

conn ikev2-vpn
    auto=add
    compress=no
    type=tunnel
    keyexchange=ikev2
    fragmentation=yes
    forceencaps=yes
    dpdaction=clear
    dpddelay=300s
    rekey=no
    left=%any
    leftid=<server_ip>
    leftcert=server-cert.pem
    leftsendcert=always
    leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
    right=%any
    rightid=%any
    rightauth=eap-mschapv2
    rightsourceip=10.0.0.0/24
    rightdns=8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
    rightsendcert=never
    eap_identity=%identity
    ike=chacha20poly1305-sha512-curve25519-prfsha512,aes256gcm16-sha384-prfsha384-ecp384,aes256-sha1-modp1024,aes128-sha1-modp1024,3des-sha1-modp1024!
    esp=chacha20poly1305-sha512,aes256gcm16-ecp384,aes256-sha256,aes256-sha1,3des-sha1!

And this is the ipconfig from a Windows client:
Scheda PPP Milano:

   Suffisso DNS specifico per connessione:
   Indirizzo IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1
   Subnet mask . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Gateway predefinito . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0

And also the ifconfig from RHEL server
enp0s6: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9000
        inet 10.0.0.126  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        inet6 fe80::17ff:fe01:a583  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2603:c027:1:ef00:aa56:5349:a80:3f9a  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 02:00:17:01:a5:83  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 423251  bytes 426753563 (406.9 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 481537  bytes 439060334 (418.7 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 10  bytes 656 (656.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10  bytes 656 (656.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

